# cp to a previous directory using the shortcut -

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, cp

I am a beginner with Ubuntu and I tried searching for an answer for this but I can't find one that covers this and I am confused by the output I am getting.  I know you can use cp to copy to a parent directory by using .. or copy to your current with ., but I was trying to copy to my previous directory using - and I am getting a weird result.

```
cp testfile1.ogg -
```

This doesn't copy the file testfile1.ogg to my previous directory.  It creates a file called - in my current directory.  If I try

```
cp testfile1.ogg ..
```

then this copies testfile1.ogg to the parent directory.  Why does using the - shortcut not work?

Comment: Use the `$OLDPWD` environment variable that `bash` sets for you. `-` is not a shortcut for "previous directory", it is often used for `STDOUT`, but that's a per-command choice, check the `man` page for the command.

Comment: Ok.  Thank you.  I was thinking I could use - since cd - would take me to the previous directory.  Any idea why Ubuntu creates a file called - in my current directory.  That seems weird since I am using the cp command and since I used the - it ignores the file I tried to copy and instead creates a file called -

Comment: It copied the file you told it to copy to a file named `-`

Comment: Oh.  That makes sense.  I was looking at this completely wrong.  Thanks!!